# Any 'tray' for cloud indicator in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, system-tray

New to 17.10 and its iteration of Gnome. I use Zoho suite, and when I run the cloud sync app, it doesn't show anywhere in my tray. Any elegant solution for enabling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to enable the panel integration. You can use an extension like [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/).

You can read this guide to know [how to use GNOME extensions in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/). Just a disclaimer, I wrote this guide.

Comment: @uxbal did it work? If yes, you may mark it as solved :)